# Alternatives to Github Insights (pulse)?

Tags: github, analytics

GitHub insights is limited. [image: GitHub Insights > Pulse]

Similar to GitHub insights, I want to get trends for my open source repo on GitHub. That would allow me to view pull request counts, issues, forks etc. for a custom period of time.

Are there any online tools that does that? Google search isin't helping. :(

I have seen a similar tool previously but cannot find it in my History. Any help appreciated.

Comment: You're looking for a tool that would have an integration with Github APIs to get the same datas from Github repositories insights ? 

I don't know if there is any tool like this on the market yet. In your case, wouldn't building a custom script / automation to get informations you need be easier / faster ? (something like this: https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/formulas-insights for example)